# JavaScript event handler

Tags: javascript, event-listener, attachevent

I am trying to fix a bug with the mouseenter and mouseleave handler.

```
listener.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    element.style.visibility = "visible";
}, true);

listener.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
}, true);
```

The events work as expected except for when i am moving the mouse over the element it flashes the mouse leave event.

Any fixes for this?

Plain javascript solutions only, please (no 3rd party libraries).

Comment: When you move the mouse rapidly across the object, it should flash because you will first get a mouseenter and then a mouseleave.  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: In any case, you should probably just do this in CSS with `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer in Javascript is only "hovering" the topmost (visible) element.

This means that if you've say a background div and when "entering" it you display another div on top of it the cursor will exit the background to enter the new div.

May be you can just set opacity to `0` instead of hiding the div and leave it always "visible" (also placing the event handler in the appearing div, not in the background one).

Comment: thats a cheap way to solve the issue instead i had it check the list of parents and if a parent was that of my element the event was not triggered. Note that opacity gives issues in early versions of IE.

Comment: @user3330630: I stopped quite a bit ago caring about what IE authors do intentionally to break the internet and chain users to their non-standard solutions.

Comment: Thats because your not a real developer. shame on you for having a stackoverflow account.

Comment: @user3330630: I am a developer, but indeed my main business is not about writing web applications and I mainly play with js/html for fun. Fiddling with IE bad implementation issues (or, if you want to be just a bit paranoid, bending to their agenda) is however not my idea of fun. Long ago I realized that in all my js/html software there was a code path for every other possible browser and one for IE. I simply decided to stop following their crazy plot.

Answer (score 0):

There is property named `relatedTarget` in the mouse event, which would help you fix it. you should check if it is not in the area like:

```
listener.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event){
    if(!event.relatedTarget ||
       (event.relatedTarget != listener && event.relatedTarget.parentNode != listener))
        element.style.visibility = "visible";
    else
        alert("I am still in listener area but mouseleave got triggered :)))");
}, true);
```

The point here is I have checked only for the first parent level, but you better create a function to check it for all the DOM tree in the `listener` node. I mean it could be one of the nested childNodes in the `listener` node.

I know it seems kind of weird, but it is the way it is, sometimes when it enters to a child nodes area `mouseleave` gets triggered.

Comment: @cookiemonster: I updated my answer to clarify this weird situation.

Comment: Oh sorry i already found a solution, i will post it when i get 10 reputation. i wont forget.